# Real World MapReduce examples

Tags: mapreduce

Can I get some real world code example of MapReduce? From the tutorials I've read, they all talks about the word count example. I get that, but I have a hard time coming up with ideas of utilizing it other than word count.

Is there any example of MapReduce applications other than count?

Comment: [Here](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/unique_items_map_reduce/) is a good page that describes computing "Unique item counts". It's a multiple stage MR that is a bit more complex and helps get your mind working the "map reduce way". If you're looking for an example with hadoop there is a SO question about it over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885394/whats-the-best-way-to-count-unique-visitors-with-hadoop).

Comment: You can get good real time usage of hadoop by looking at [Nutch crawler](http://nutch.apache.org/). Its been build to work on hadoop.