# MapReduce program to count unique users by day

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to create a MapReduce program to count how many unique users use a site, per day. My data set is a .csv file and I am extracting; `(date, user)` where date is a string of the form `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm`, and user is also a string.

I know in scala I would do something (roughly) along the lines of;

```
val rdd = data.map(x => (x.date -> user))
val users = rdd.reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

to get a list of users per day and then I could count unique users.

My issue is I need to do this in Hadoop, using python to create files for the mapper and reducer. I am not very experienced with python and am having trouble deciding how to filter the users by date.

Below is my attempt for the mapper:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
   line = line.strip()
   splits = line.split(",")
   timestamp = splits[0]
   user = splits[1]                
   print '%s\t%s\t%s' % (user, timestamp)
```

but I really have no idea how to approach creating the reducer. Any help would be very appreciated.

I have also seen this ask: [What's the best way to count unique visitors with Hadoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885394/whats-the-best-way-to-count-unique-visitors-with-hadoop)
and would like to follow the recommendation given, but again, I have no idea how to start creating the reducer.py file to do this.

Comment: You have a Scala idea, so why use MapReduce instead of Spark? And why do you **need** to use python?

Comment: @cricket_007 to make me appreciate Spark more? No just kidding, I'm currently studying MapReduce and this is the only example I can't work out how to do with MapReduce. As for python it's what I have the most experience and examples of within this context (even if my experience is very limited).

Comment: Okay, well, first `print '%s\t%s\t%s` is trying to print 3 things, and you only provide 2. Secondly, this isn't much different than word count, right? You simply output `timestamp, user, 1`. Your reducer then reads again from `sys.stdin` (like you for the mapper) and sums all the ones for timestamps of the same day, then outputs the `user, count` and optionally, the timestamp

Comment: Or, if you really need MapReduce, try Hive or Pig